# Plot many time-series columns in one graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a big dataframe with roughly 100 columns and I'm trying to plot all the time-series in one graph. Is there an easy way to deal with it, without specifying every y-axis manually?

This would be a simple example with these time-series: `02K W`, `03K W`, and `04K W`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'index':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 0.1, 3, 'nan', 0.2], 
    '03K W':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0, 0.6], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 8.2, 4.2, 5.3]}) 

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1 = df1.set_index('index')
```

So far, I manually specify all y-axis to plot the individual time-series.

```
plt.plot(df1['Date'], df1['02K W'])
plt.plot(df1['Date'], df1['03K W'])
plt.plot(df1['Date'], df1['04K W'])
```

Is there a more elegant way to specify the relevant columns for the plot?

Comment: Use for loop. Iterate over a list of column names

Comment: do you see a pattern in your 02K W...03K W and so forth. Just use iterator if thats the case.

Comment: No, there is no specific pattern, I try to plot everything except the index & date column.

Comment: `df.plot(x='Date')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'index':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 0.1, 3, 'nan', 0.2], 
    '03K W':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0, 0.6], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 8.2, 4.2, 5.3]}) 

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1 = df1.set_index('index')

for col in df1.colums[1:]:
    plt.plot(df1['Date'], df1[col])
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more elegant way to specify the relevant columns for the plot? ... [I'm trying] to plot everything except the index & date column.

Set `Date` as the index, which will overwrite the current `index` index. That will leave all columns except `index` and `Date`, so you can just use [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```py
df1.set_index('Date').plot()
```

Or as [Quang commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69826409/plot-many-time-series-columns-in-one-graph/69826473#comment123429134_69826409), use `x='Date'`:

```py
df1.plot(x='Date')
```

Note that you have a `'nan'` string in your sample data. If this is true in your real data, you should convert those to the real `np.nan`, e.g., with [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) or [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can `melt` your columns and use `seaborn.lineplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df1.replace('nan', float('nan')).melt(id_vars=['Date']),
             x='Date', y='value', hue='variable'
            )
```

output:

[image: lineplot]